# Cannot install NIS package

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I cannot install NIS package on Ubuntu 14.04 (upgrade from 13.10). When I try to run `apt-get install nis` I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nis is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  hostname:i386 hostname

E: Package 'nis' has no installation candidate
```

Could someone advise? Could it be a problem with repository setup?

Thank you.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `find /etc/apt/ -name "*.list" -exec bash -c 'printf "\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" "========" "$1" "========"; cat "$1"' _ {} \;`

Comment: Did you enable the `universe` repository? that appears to be where it is: [nis](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nis)

Answer (score 0):

Read the messages.

```
Package nis is not available,

However the following packages replace it:  
hostname:i386 hostname
```

So, if you want the functionality, install `hostname` or `hostname:i386`.

If you want to play with the NIS source, you will have to find it on the web.